# highlight plot with border shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to add a red border around a plot to highlight the plot when a button is pressed.

In the code below there are two buttons. When one of the buttons is clicked, a reactiveValue updates which plot should be highlighted.

```
library(shinyjs)
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  actionButton(inputId = "button1", label = "Border Left"),
  actionButton(inputId = "button2", label = "Border Right"),
  plotOutput("distPlot1"),
  plotOutput("distPlot2")
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  r <- reactiveValues(
      plot1Border = TRUE,
      plot2Border = FALSE
    )

  output$distPlot1 <- renderPlot({
    x <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x))
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = r$my_color)
  })
  output$distPlot2 <- renderPlot({
    x <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x))
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = r$my_color)
  })

  observeEvent(input$button1, {
    removeClass("button2", "btn-primary")
    addClass("button1", "btn-primary")
    r$plot1Border <- TRUE
    r$plot2Border <- FALSE
  })

  observeEvent(input$button2, {
    removeClass("button1", "btn-primary")
    addClass("button2", "btn-primary")
    r$plot1Border <- FALSE
    r$plot2Border <- TRUE
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The trouble is I couldn't even figure out how to highlight plot staticly. I added this to UI but nothing happened:

```
tags$head(
            tags$style(HTML("
                #distPlot1 {
                    border: 2px solid red;
                }"
            ))
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

In `tags$style()` don't prefix CSS class names with `#` but with `.`:

```r
library(shinyjs)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  actionButton(inputId = "button1", label = "Border Left"),
  actionButton(inputId = "button2", label = "Border Right"),
  plotOutput("distPlot1"),
  plotOutput("distPlot2"),
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(".redBox {border: 2px solid red;}"
    ))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$distPlot1 <- renderPlot({
    x <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x))
    hist(x, breaks = bins)
  })
  output$distPlot2 <- renderPlot({
    x <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x))
    hist(x, breaks = bins)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$button1, {
    removeClass("distPlot2", "redBox")
    addClass("distPlot1", "redBox")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$button2, {
    removeClass("distPlot1", "redBox")
    addClass("distPlot2", "redBox")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```